# TypeScript not considering ternary operator with undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, conditional-operator

```js
interface FormikInstance {
    touched: {[key: string]: boolean | undefined}
    errors: {[key: string]: string | undefined}
    status?: {[key: string]: string}
}

const useFormikErrors = (formik: FormikInstance) => {
    const showErrors = (fieldName: string): boolean => {
        const status = formik.status ? formik.status[fieldName] : undefined;
        return !!formik.touched[fieldName] && (!!formik.errors[fieldName] || !!status);
    }
    const getErrors = (fieldName: string): string => {
        const status = formik.status ? formik.status[fieldName] : undefined;
        // errors is of type: string | undefined, but should be string
        let errors = formik.errors[fieldName] === undefined ? '' : formik.errors[fieldName];
        errors += status === undefined ? '' : status;
        return errors;
    }
    return [showErrors, getErrors]
};
```

The problem is marked in a comment. The errors variable is `string | undefined`. Does typescript consider ternary operators, or am I missing something obvious here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that checking for `undefined` specifically does not rule out all "empty" scenarios - it could also be `null` or other similar falsy value that you might not necessarily want to render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the type of a *nested* property doesn't narrow its type, unfortunately. You can fix it by extracting the value into a standalone variable first (which also helps make the code more DRY):

```
const fieldErrors = formik.errors[fieldName];
let errors = fieldErrors === undefined ? '' : fieldErrors;
errors += status === undefined ? '' : status;
return errors;
```